# HTC Sense Personal Dictionary Doesn't Show Word

Tags: htc-sense, delete, dictionary

HTC EVO 4G LTE Running Android 4.1.1

I was typing along and was trying to make a point in a text by capitalizing the word LOT. Well, I accidently saved it to the custom dictionary on the next keystroke, didn't think anything of it, but now everytime I try and type "lot" I get the full caps version.

I've gone to the Personal Dictionary and removed some other entries that accidently made it in, but the LOT one doesn't show up. Any advice?